# how to use keyvault certificate to connect to servicefabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-keyvault

i have a service fabric cluster in azure and i have a powershell script to connect, however i would like to know if there is a way to use the certificate from azure keyvault without having to actually download and store the cert on the local computer

i tried to pull the certificate from the keyvault and able to pull the thumbprint but without the -storelocation switch, the script cannot authenticate and connect, the fabric cluster is secure and we are trying to avoid storing anything on computers

```
Connect-serviceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint 'testcluster'
    -X509Credential `
    -FindType FindByThumbprint `
    -FindValue <certificate common name> `
    -StoreLocation CurrentUser ` # wondering if this can point to azure keyvault
    -StoreName My
```

Comment: Would a jump host help? You still need the cert but at least it’s in one place on a remote machine and you could still use the user credentials to authenticate to the jump host. It’s a thought.

Answer (score 0):

well it seems there is no way to pull the information from the certificate in the keyvault without having to download it, so in the end i am downloading the cert and importing it, restarting the fabric and then deleting the cert

thank you all